ESP32 Telegram Stops sending messages after the two message in CTBot header file
I am now creating a ESP32 based NTP clock with facility of message display to the MAX7219 led matrix whenever a person send message through the BOT that I have Created... Every thing works fine. But after reading 2-3 message from Telegram, the display didnot show any further message and jump to next switch condition.
In this project, I am using CTBot version 2.1.13 (latest), ArduinoJson version 6.19.4.
The Code is here under:
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "CTBot.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define BOTtoken "707859XXXX:AAHSWfgsOiTKEV5FC9gTG2EMnD79J2XXXXX";
WiFiClientSecure client;
CTBot myBot;


#include <WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Font_Data.h"
#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>

#define ThermistorPin 35
#define buzzer 2
#define NUM_ZONES 3
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
#define DATA_PIN 13    // pin connection in esp32
#define CLK_PIN 14     // pin connection in esp32
#define CS_PIN 12      // pin connection in esp32
#define MAX_DEVICES 4  //maximum max7219 module connected in chain
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

#define SPEED_TIME 50  // Speed of the transition
#define PAUSE_TIME 1000


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
// Global variables
float temp = 0;
char message[20] = "";
char szMesg[150] = "";
uint8_t degC[] = { 6, 3, 3, 28, 34, 34, 34 };  // Deg C
uint8_t clear = 0x00;
bool isPM;

char second[3], minute[3], hour[3], day[10], date[3], month[10], year[5];
const char* ssid = "HomeFiber_4g";      // SSID of local network
const char* password = "Hima@nilu123";  //Password of wifi

String myssid(ssid);
String mypass(password);
String token = "7078596485:AAHSWfgsOiTKEV5FC9gTG2EMnD79J2j087Q";  // REPLACE myToken WITH YOUR TELEGRAM BOT TOKEN


const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";  //NTP server for getting time
const long gmtOffset_sec = 19800;        //Set your timezone in second, Here I used for India(GMT+ 5.30hr)
const int daylightOffset_sec = 0;        //Daylight saving is off here for India


const long intervalo = 1000;  //Time interval between checking messages (in milliseconds)
int lastMinute = -1;
//getting time from NTP Server
void printLocalTime() {
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
    getError(szMesg);
    return;
  }
  strftime(day, sizeof(day), "%A", &timeinfo);
  strftime(month, sizeof(month), "%B", &timeinfo);
  strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%d", &timeinfo);
  strftime(year, sizeof(year), "%Y", &timeinfo);
  strftime(hour, sizeof(hour), "%H", &timeinfo);
  strftime(minute, sizeof(minute), "%M", &timeinfo);
  strftime(second, sizeof(second), "%S", &timeinfo);
}

void getError(char* psz) {
  const char* err = "error";
  sprintf(psz, "%s", err);
  Serial.println(psz);
}
void getTime(char* psz, bool f = true) {
  int hourInt = atoi(hour);
  int hour12 = hourInt % 12;
  if (hour12 == 0) {
    hour12 = 12;
  }
  isPM = hourInt >= 12;
  sprintf(psz, "%02d%c%02d", hour12, (f ? ':' : ' '), atoi(minute));
}


void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    myBot.wifiConnect(myssid, mypass);
    myBot.setTelegramToken(token);  // set the telegram bot token
    if (myBot.testConnection())
      Serial.println("\ntestConnection OK");
    else
      Serial.println("\ntestConnection NOK");
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
  delay(5000);
  printLocalTime();
  P.begin(NUM_ZONES);
  P.setZone(0, 0, 3);
  P.setIntensity(0);
  P.addChar('$', degC);
  P.displayZoneText(0, szMesg, PA_CENTER, SPEED_TIME, 0, PA_PRINT, PA_NO_EFFECT);
}


void loop() {

  getTemperature();
  printLocalTime();
  static uint32_t lastTime = 0;  // millis() memory
  static uint8_t display = 0;    // Current display mode
  static bool flasher = false;   // Seconds passing flasher

  if (atoi(second) == 0 && lastMinute != 0) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }
  lastMinute = atoi(second);
  P.displayAnimate();

  if (P.getZoneStatus(0)) {
    switch (display) {
      case 0:  // Temperature deg Celsius
        P.setFont(0, nullptr);
        P.setPause(0, 5000);
        P.setTextEffect(0, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, PA_SCROLL_UP);
        display++;
        dtostrf(temp, 3, 1, szMesg);
        strcat(szMesg, "$");
        Serial.print("Temperature: ");
        Serial.println(temp);
        break;

      case 1:  // Clock
        P.setFont(0, numeric7Seg);
        P.setTextEffect(0, PA_PRINT, PA_NO_EFFECT);
        P.setPause(0, 0);
        if ((millis() - lastTime) >= 500) {
          lastTime = millis();
          getTime(szMesg, flasher);
          Serial.println(szMesg);
          flasher = !flasher;
        }
        if ((atoi(second) == 5) && (atoi(second) <= 30)) {
          P.setTextEffect(0, PA_PRINT, PA_WIPE_CURSOR);
          display++;
        }
        break;

      case 2:  // Calendar
        P.setFont(0, nullptr);
        P.setTextEffect(0, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, PA_SCROLL_LEFT);
        display++;
        getDays(szMesg);
        P.setPause(0, 3000);
        break;
      case 3:
        TBMessage msg;
        if (myBot.getNewMessage(msg, 0))  //Check if any message arrived
        {
         // blinker(1000, 3);
          msg.text.toCharArray(szMesg, 20);
          //Serial.println(msg.text);
          myBot.sendMessage(msg.sender.id, "Hello, " + msg.sender.firstName + msg.sender.lastName + ", Your Message: \n" + msg.text + "\ndisplayed on system...\n");
          P.setFont(0, nullptr);
          P.displayZoneText(0, szMesg, PA_CENTER, SPEED_TIME, 0, PA_PRINT, PA_SCROLL_LEFT);
          P.setPause(0, 2000);
        }
        display = 0;
        break;
    }
    P.displayReset(0);
  }
}

float getTemperature() {
  float R1 = 9950;  // value of R1 on board
  float logR2, R2;
  //steinhart-hart coeficients for thermistor
  float c1 = 0.001129148, c2 = 0.000234125, c3 = 0.0000000876741;
  long ADC_Value = analogRead(ThermistorPin);
  R2 = R1 * (4096.0 / (float)ADC_Value - 1.0);  //calculate resistance on thermistor
  logR2 = log(R2);
  temp = (1.0 / (c1 + c2 * logR2 + c3 * logR2 * logR2 * logR2));  // temperature in Kelvin
  temp = temp - 273.15;                                           //convert Kelvin to Celcius
  return temp;
}

void getDays(char* psz) {
  String dayStr = String(day);
  String monthStr = String(month);
  String subStr1 = dayStr.substring(0, 3);
  String subStr2 = monthStr.substring(0, 3);
  strcpy(szMesg, subStr2.c_str());
  strcat(szMesg, " ");
  strcat(szMesg, subStr1.c_str());
  strcat(szMesg, " ");
  strcat(szMesg, date);
  Serial.println(szMesg);
}

void blinker(long interval, int maxBlinks) {
   unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  int blinkCount = 0;       // Counter to keep track of blinks
   // Number of LED state changes (2 blinks = 4 state changes)

  if (blinkCount < (maxBlinks*2) && currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // Save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // Toggle the LED state
    int buzzerState = digitalRead(buzzer);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, !buzzerState);

    // Increment the blink counter
    blinkCount++;
  }
}

I have tried with multiple code shifting but problem has not solved.

If myBot.sendMessage() doesn't work although it's being called, check the int32_t return code for starters. Also, modify your library to turn on the DEBUG_ALL mode in CTBotDefines.h so you can see error messages on the serial port. https://github.com/shurillu/CTBot/blob/master/src/CTBotDefines.h#L15 https://github.com/shurillu/CTBot/blob/master/src/CTBot.h#L94-L104

I think the problem with ESP HEAP MEMORY. I got the following message during running of bot properly: getNewMessage JSON: {
"ok": true,
"result": []
}
ESP32 with https verification
Connected using DNS
--->sendCommand  : Free heap memory: 207268 / 210316 - 174 ms..                                       However after some times the system halts and error message is :     ESP32 with https verification
Unable to connect to Telegram server
getNewMessage error: ArduinoJson deserialization error code: EmptyInput

The print ESP.freeHeap() in every loop iteration. If it goes down slowly, then you have a memory leak somewhere, where something is not deinitializated correctly.

@maximilian how to resolve this problem.

I got the Solution very simple.. I Downgrade the ESP32 board version to 1.0.4. and the solution
